# Pandas: How to get column B values for the rows whose column A values are in a given list

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have below data frame named `df` where the column names are `Name` and `Age`:

[image]

and I have a list `[Jack, Sarah]`. I want to get `[28, 21]` (the order of the names is important). How can I do this most effectively?

Comment: `df.loc[df.Name.isin(['Jack', 'Sarah']), 'Age'].tolist()`

Comment: Looks like this does not keep the order of the input list (i.e., if the input list is `['Sarah', 'Jack']`, then I would get `[21, 28]` not `[28,21]`), which is something that I need (see my question) and here is my solution keeping the order:
`df.index = df.Name` followed by `df.Age[input_list]`